# How can I create subclass at run-time to map some properties then cast it back to parent class?

Tags: c#

Consider this `People` class:

```
public class People
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }    
    public virtual ushort Age { get; set; }
}
```

I have some third party implementations that can obtain people data but with a little variations. For example, I have a method that is able to retrieve data for `StrangePeople`:

```
    public class StrangePeople
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }        
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    }
    ...
    StrangePeople someone = GetData<StrangePeople>();
```

Due to the amount of classes and variations I trying to found a way to generate a runtime subclass of `People` that can translate the data so I can cast it back to `People` later. In other words, with minimum effort generate a subclass like this:

```
public class StrangePeopleTranslator : People
{
    private ushort? _mAge = null;

    public override ushort Age
    {
        get
        {
            if (_mAge == null)
            {
                DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
                int age = today.Year - BirthDate.Year;
                if (BirthDate > today.AddYears(-age)) age--;
                _mAge = age;
            }

            return _mAge.GetValueOrDefault();
        }
        set
        {
            _mAge = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}

...

People someoneElse = (People)GetData<StrangePeopleTranslator>();
```

Maybe the run-time subclass it's bit overkill... I don't know.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "run-time subclass". Do you mean using reflection for automatic code generation in any way?

Comment: @matcheek Yeah, I looked at c# type builder, but if its the only way to do something like that I'll give up. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.aspx

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the `Decorator Pattern`?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing you can do is provide an implicit cast overload.  That way you can convert from `StrangePeople` to `People`, like this:

```
public class StrangePeople
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator People(StrangePeople strangePerson)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        int age = today.Year - strangePerson.BirthDate.Year;
        if (strangePerson.BirthDate > today.AddYears(-age))
        {
            age--;
        }

        return new People
                    {
                        Name = strangePerson.Name,
                        Age = (ushort) age
                    };
    }
```

Then you could do this:

```
People someoneElse = GetData<StrangePeopleTranslator>();
```

You don't even need a cast.

Comment: Very nice approach, but I'm still needing to define dozen of sub-classes. I'll use your solution anyway but I'm wondering if I can't create the `StrangePeople` class in a more dynamic way, like reading  his properties from database and passing a delegate to act as the implicit caster...

Comment: @cvsguimaraes, note this is not a new subclass, it's a new method (operator) on the `StrangePeople` class which I understand you already have.  What other subclasses do you need to create?

Comment: The `StrangePeople` class was just an representation of which kind of structure `GetData` is waiting for...

Answer (score 1):

Well, depending on how much effort you're willing to put in to this, you could use a single subclass with dynamically generated `Func`s using `System.Linq.Expressions.`  You'll need to be using C#4 for full functionality here.

The basic idea:

```
public class Subclass : People
{
    public Func<DateTime, ushort> BirthDateToAge;
    ushort _mAge;

    public override ushort Age
    {
        get { return AgeImpl(_mAge); }
        set { _mAge = value; }
    }
}

// And then somewhere else where you'd want to create the "subclass"
var people = new Subclass();
Func<DateTime, ushort> setter = (Func<DateTime, ushort>)(bday => (ushort)CalcElapsedYears(bday));
people.AgeImpl = setter;
```

You'll probably need to factor it differently, but the basic concept is the same: create a generic subclass that can operate entirely via `Func<>`s, and then build those `Func<>`s when you do your reflection or whatnot.

It's kind harebrained, but it should work.